# Can rgbdslam_electric run on OS:10.04 with electric?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I did as the following website:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam_electric

After I had run this command:"rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam",it shows as below:

### ...

### [ rosmake ] Output from build of package eigen written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/sven/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121211-095817/eigen/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< eigen [FAIL] [ 0.06 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package eigen.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] All 3 linesg2o: 4.0 sec ]                [ 1 Active 36/53 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
svn --non-interactive --config-dir /home/sven/ros/g2o/svnconf co  https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o/trunk build/g2o
svn: OPTIONS of 'https://svn.openslam.org/data/svn/g2o/trunk': Server certificate verification failed: issuer is not trusted (https://svn.openslam.org)

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package g2o written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/sven/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121211-095817/g2o/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< g2o [FAIL] [ 3.98 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package g2o.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 38 packages with 2 failures.
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory
[ rosmake ] /home/sven/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20121211-095817

ɪs there any problems with the package or this package can not run on Ubuntu 10.04 with electric?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50133/can-rgbdslam_electric-run-on-os:10.04-with-electric?/) by [sven_007](https://answers.ros.org/users/1417/sven_007/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2012-12-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That looks like you are having issues with access to the svn server not an issue with your OS.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0